# Store and currency based on visitor's IP in Magento2.1

Tags: php, magento-2.1, extensions

I want to use store and currency should change based on visitor's IP (i.e., Geo IP (aka) Geo tagging) in **Magento2.1**. It should be automated like when the USA customer opens our site, the site should use USD.

Is there any free extensions available for this in  Magento 2.1? If so, Please suggest me. I have a very short period of time to do this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some paid extensions, If you want to create your own extension, Please follow these instructions.

-> Create a module in Magento 2.

-> Create a observer on `controller_action_predispatch` event.

-> Get customer country from Geo Ip address .

-> Add Some logic like if Country A is detected switch to Store store-a else switch to store-b.

-> Add some session filter so that your function is not executed once the store is switched.

```
if($currentSore != $switchedStore){
    $storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($switchedStore);/* storeCookieManager = \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface */
    $response->setRedirect('your.store.redirect.url'); /* $response  = \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface */
    $response->sendResponse();
}
```